# How to add JMS Message Header Property from WLST

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I have a scenario, where i need to use WLST to move messages from one UDQ to another. Now i want to add a specific JMS Message Header property to carry a constant value.

I know that properties of a produced JMS Message are immutable and thus one has to copy, clear and then add all the copied properties along with the new property to effectively "ADD" a new property to the JMS Message. This is very easily done using the JMS Java API.

What i want to ask is how to do the same using WLST shell scripts?

Any pointers to achieve the task is more than welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WLST does not have specific functions to achieve this. The best way is to directly use Java JMS API from your WLST script.

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel but using the JMS API in WLST will entail in creating consumers for the Queue. My objective was to avoid creating consumers and thus we selected the WLST way to move messages between UDQ. Is there any way to add the message properties without creating consumers?

Comment: I'm afraid you have no choice but read, update and post each message in order to add your custom properties. You will also need to read and post from/to different queues.